# An adjective to describe eyes like these?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Some people have eyes that look rather different than most people's, with their whole upper eyelids (*) being very visible. Is there a term or an adjective for eyes like these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

(*) By "eyelid" I meant the part *below* the eyelid crease (Perhaps that's anatomically wrong)

Comment: Are you looking for [hooded](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hooded)?

Comment: @WeatherVane 'hooded' seems to be the opposite of these

Comment: It was a comment suggestion because I don't follow the description: in the second picture the whole upper eyelid isn't visible.

Comment: @WeatherVane It must be dark makeup and/or shadow.

Comment: I always thought that 'hooded' means the upper lid is seen to cover the eyeball like a hood. Perhaps 'droopy' then.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample sentence or two in which you leave an empty line like `____` to indicate where the term you desire would fall syntactically. Some possible examples: ① *His eyes didn’t `____` as much in the morning as they did at night.* ② *I couldn’t help but notice how very `____` her eyes were.*  ② *I had never seen eyes as `____` as hers!* ④ *My doctor told me I had `____` eyes but not to worry about it.* ⑤ *The levator palpebrae of the affected side would undergo a controlateral nerve stimulus sufficient to allow elevation of the `____` eyelid.*

Comment: Please add -a lot- more detail to describe what you're thinking of.  The two pictures do not give anywhere near to something common. You may want to consider explaining what the eyelids -do not- look like. A picture means something to you because you see in it what you're thinking, but it doesn't translate into other people's thoughts. Is it simply that you can see the entire eyelid even when open? Is it a particular curve to it? Is the eyelid always smooth or can it be wrinkled? Does the shape of the orbital bridge, the bone that the hair of the eyebrow is on, matter?

Comment: It's Nancy Pelosi! I was stumped there; fun game!

Comment: @Mitch *"Is it simply that you can see the entire eyelid even when open?"* Yes (up to the eyelid crease). I think it's caused by a combination of low eyelid/brow fat and/or eye sockets being relatively big for the eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**heavy-lidded**:

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lidded)

---

> lidded

> 2: having lids especially of a specified kind —usually used in combination
> //heavy-lidded eyes

---

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/heavy-lidded-eyes)

> heavy-lidded eyes

> eyes with large eyelids

---

Glamour [writes](https://www.glamour.com/story/heavy-lidded-eyes-makeup-penelope-cruz):

> Got Heavy-Lidded Eyes? Here's a Perfect Makeup Look for You

with a picture of Penelope Cruz.

[image]

---

This strikes me as a misnomer though. Eyes like these should have been called **light-lidded**, because they literally have lighter eyelids.

Answer (score 5):

In English, eyelids are said to be **hooded or prominent**. One or the other. Not both at the same time. The pictures show prominent eyelids.

> Next up on my eye makeup series is makeup for prominent eyelids. This
> will also feature tips for deep set eyes. Those two types of eyes
> often go together, so I will address both in this blog.
>
> I am often envious of these eyes, as I have hooded eyes and I have to
> contour the crap out of my eyes to give them dimension! Every eye
> shape has its own beauty and benefits, and every shape has its
> difficulties!

[prominent eyelids](http://pureanada.blogspot.com/2019/10/how-to-makeup-for-prominent-eyelids.html)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think it could be clearer. It gets the point across.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, she says prominent eyes are often found with deep-set eyes. Then right after that she says: She is envious because her eyes are hooded. So, she has contrasted prominent AND hooded.

Comment: Then please make it clear which term refers to the images displayed in the question. Because I read the answer as saying they can be called either "hooded" or "prominent". Just to be clear, *hooded eyes* are not the same as a prominent eyes, the former is where the excess flesh under the brow effectively covers the upper eyelid when the eye is open.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: In English, we say a person is fat **or** thin. Is that ambiguous? Maybe I'm used to addressing translators, in short hand style. I thought that by reading the two paragraphs, it was clear. I guess it wasn't.

Comment: I show you a picture of a fat person, you tell me a person can be fat or thin. That doesn't tell me what the word for a big person is.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, that does not tell you what the word for a big person is. But that is a third term. I am trying to come to an agreement here, and I explained my thinking to you. I have now edited the question so it should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

As a medical condition this is called "*drooping eyelids*" or "*ptosis*".

[image] ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=eyelids+drooping&client=firefox-b-d&ei=MmoTYffEHMuPlwS61o0I&oq=eyelids+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYAjIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CggAEEcQsAMQiwNKBQg8EgExSgQIQRgAUINGWINGYJhfaAFwAngAgAHQAYgB2AKSAQUwLjEuMZgBAKABAcgBCLgBAsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

However, it appears that this term can be used in the description of someone's eyelids as a characterization of their inherited natural position.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Countess_Gisela/dOsyAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22drooping+eyelids%22&pg=PA49&printsec=frontcover)) "Take Gisela away, Frau von Herbeck," he said with perfect composure. His entire self-possession was most striking in contrast with the passion displayed by the blind woman. The very shape of the man's head and features was calculated to express high-bred repose. His
drooping eyelids veiled his glance , and made it unfathomable , and his slightly aquiline nose looked as if chiselled on the face , which , although not full , never revealed the play of a single muscle .

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Picture_of_Dorian_Gray/wY3uBQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22drooping+eyelids%22&pg=PA128&printsec=frontcover)) Wilde's  own drooping eyelids have been frequently remarked upon: they were satirized in Aubrey Beardsley's illustrations to Salome.

[image]

*Oscar Wilde*

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Temptation_s_Darling/nqp_DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22drooping+eyelids%22&pg=PT188&printsec=frontcover)) He had drooping eyelids as if he'd just awoken from slumber that gave him an aura of sensuality. He was older than she would have liked, no longer a young ...

Comment:  Is this something eyes do or something eyelids do—or both?        Is then what you’re suggesting here for the answer actually the verb *to droop*? Or the adjective *droopy* as in *droopy drawers*? Or the deverbal adjective *drooping* used attributively? Or the past participle *drooped* used passively or predicatively or attributively? Or the adverb *droopingly*? Or the noun *ptosis*, possibly used attributively?  Or the adjective *ptotic*? Or the adverb *ptoticly*? Or the adjective *ptotical*? Or the adverb *ptotically*? 

Comment: @tchrist "He glanced at her through his ptotic. lizard-like eyes." I did get a laugh out of your comment here and up there, I have to say.

Comment: @tchrist Suggesting, in this context of finding a term, is beyond my  "function":  there might be a couple of terms yet to appear on the post, and I think I have determined one, so, that wouldn't be judicious. I think that even if the term "drooping eyelids" has two uses (medical (plenty of occurrences) and current language with no medical overtones (comparatively rare), it can be used in that latter domain. There is a possible problem of ambiguity (that the context should clear up) with the verb and the deverbal adjective; one thing is certain and that is that in such constructions as (1/3)

Comment: @tchrist "his eyelids drooped" one can read the assertion of a momentary situation (due to weariness, or a particular state of mind perhaps), but I have no certitude as to whether this is a valid enunciation as the  characterization of the permanent shape of someone's eyelid aperture. "Ptosis" and its derivatives are definitely out, I think; inherited characteristics may be changed through aesthetic surgery but they are not to be associated with medical conditions, it's best to keep the two things apart; (2/3)

Comment: @tchrist after all, although eyelids not fully retracted seem to be undesirable, there are people who might not be so disatified with this particularity of their eye shape. One might note that both the present day leader of Japan and that of China, Shinzo Abe and Xi Jinping, have  this feature in a characteristic degree ([ref.](https://english.kyodonews.net/news/2018/07/377bf6a480d4-abe-eyes-visit-to-china-in-oct-to-improve-bilateral-ties.html)). (3/3)