# What's a word or term for this kind of eyes or eyelids or for describing them?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: English actor Tom Blyth]

**English actor Tom Blyth**

[image: English actress Charlotte Rampling (young)][image]

**English actress Charlotte Rampling-- young and old, respetively**

[image: Irish actor Barry Keoghan]

**Irish actor Barry Keoghan**

It looks somewhat East Asian but not quite, though there are still those who confuse people with eyes or eyelids like this, whatever it's called or however it's traditionally described, as being partly of East Asian descent because of it when they're not, just like all of the examples are not. It's not quite the same because most of the upper eyelid is hidden not because of an extra fold of skin attaching the eyelid to the bridge of the nose, like with East Asian eyelids, which makes their eyes not almond-shaped, but because of an extra-large orbital fat pad above the eye causing the skin up there to come down and cover most of the upper eyelid behind it, which is why their eyes remain clearly almond-shaped.

Anyway, I'm looking for a nontechnical word or term for this kind of eyes or eyelids or for describing them, something like how "bedroom eyes" is a term for the kind of eyes that appear perpetually heavy-lidded or half-shut. It's a common enough feature, especially among the English, that there *must* be some longstanding English term for it, like the aforementioned example "bedroom eyes" is an English term for that, or for describing it, like "bedroom" in that aforementioned example is the term for describing that. I just don't know what it is, and for all my googling, I haven't been able to find it because every search I can think of uses such words that I end up with a bunch of totally irrelevant search results.

So a little help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd call 'em *droopy*.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/572590/349876

Comment: @YosefBaskin: And you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these are **hooded eyelids** (or **hooded eyes**). It's a pretty intuitive term so you'd have an idea what it means even if you never heard it before.

> Hooded eyes are basically when the extra skin from your eyes folds down from your brow bone to the lash line of your eyes. A lot of people have hooded eyes around the world. The cause of hooded eyes can be due to a person’s age or hooded eyes since birth.
> ...
> Hooded eyes are a common feature among people. This is when a person’s eyes appear to have a small flap of extra skin on their eyes from their browbone. These is also known as hooded eyelids. To understand this easily, you can look at the attached earlobes of a person, or the shape of their eyes is only one big trait from their genetic structure. If you look into the mirror, you can easily tell if you have hooded eyes or not. It is this easy to tell. Slowly open your eyes. The skin on your eyelid is covered with the skin under your brows. Then you have hooded eyes. Hooded eyes can be mostly seen in older people. This is because their skin gets loose and loses its real structure.
> — [Belgeard](https://www.belgeard.com/what-is-the-difference-of-double-eye-lids-and-hooded-eyes/)

(The source goes on to clarify that these are not droopy eyelids because their eyes are all the way open.)

You'll see hooded eyelids on [lists of Asian eyelids](https://dreamplasticsurgery.com/5-types-of-asian-eyelids-which-do-you-have/) (not surprising given the most common surgery in many parts of east Asia is [eyelid surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_blepharoplasty)) but it's a term that's also used in the west, such as on [Buzzfeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/amphtml/chrissymahlmeister/hooded-eye-makeup), which gives us this image:

[image: monolid, upturned, downturned, hooded, round, almond]

Answer (score 0):

Hooded eyes. This term is very much used in the beauty world

Comment: We generally expect a little more detail in answers, including not only the term but also an explanation of why it's a fitting answer.

Answer (score -1):

They're **monolid** eyes.

Here's an article explaining the nuances:

https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/symptoms/22413-monolid-eyes

Comment: I don't think so. In the first and last pictures in the question, you can see a crease from one side of the eyelid to the other, which means they are double eyelids (even if subtle). As for Charlotte Rampling it's hard to tell in the pictures but I think she does have an eyelid crease but it is almost entirely underneath the rest of her eyelid in the pictures.

Comment: @Laurel: I didn't look at the pictures. I still haven't looked at them. Celebrity photos are boring.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: Thank you, I appreciate this avalanche of gratitude and good will in my direction. If only more people understood, as you do, that it is naturally polite to say "thank you" to those who furnish answers to their questions, the world would be a somewhat kinder, gentler place.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: Peachy.

Answer (score -1):

It is technically called an Epicanthal Fold.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The epicanthal fold is on the side of the eye (inner corners), not the eyelid. The question said this wasn't the term they were looking for: "most of the upper eyelid is hidden not because of an extra fold of skin attaching the eyelid to the bridge of the nose, like with East Asian eyelids". See [definition here](https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/symptoms/epicanthal-folds)